# Finite list with unknown size

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm a bit confused trying to define some structures using the math-comp library. I want to define a structure that has a function ranging from a set of values and returning lists of other values. I'm trying to define this structure as `finType` but it is failing (I assume it is because I am returning a list of unknown size).

For example:

```
Section MySection.

    Variables F V : finType.

    Structure m := M {
        f : {ffun F -> seq V};
        ...
    }.

(* Using the PcanXXXMixin family of lemmas *)

    Lemma can_m_of_prod : cancel prod_of_m m_of_prod.
      Proof. by case. Qed.

    ...

    Definition m_finMixin := CanFinMixin can_m_of_prod.
```

This throws the error `Unable to unify`.

I think the issue is that I am using `seq` and this is not finite. I am not sure how to describe that it will only return finite lists. I thought I might use n-tuples but this would require specifying a size beforehand (I could include the size along with the `F` value perhaps? I'm not sure how that would look in this notation).

Is there something I am missing or is there another approach that seems more adequate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct. We would need some more context to offer a solution; for instance, where does the bound on the size of the result list come from?

Comment: I am not really sure tbh. I mean, for now (and correct me if I'm wrong in any way) I was thinking that when I gave an actual implementation for this structure I would define the function with its values. From there I could somehow... show that each list is finite? I mean, it may sound silly because I am delaying the check that it is finite to the moment it is computed... but I don't really know how else...

Comment: Maybe I would like something in the line of `I_n`? Instead of naturals < n, something like... tuples with size smaller than n? I don't know if that makes much sense. I could include that `n` size in the structure itself and then define the function as `f : {ffun F -> 'T_n V}`

Comment: That sounds pretty good to me! You might be able to define `'T_n V` as `{i : 'I_n & i.-tuple V}` and get the `finType` structure for free.

Comment: :o ! Excuse my ignorance but I'm not very familiar with the library's notations haha. In this case, `{i : 'I_n & i.-tuple V}` would give me the naturals which are in `'I_n` and... something else? Or what do you mean by defining  `'T_n V` as such?

Comment: The notation means: the type of pairs `(i, t)`, where `i` is in `'I_n` (that is, it is a natural number bounded by `n`), and `t` is a tuple of elements of `V` whose size is `i`.

Comment: Ohh great! Thank you :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you specify the bound function directly on the type. This is for example used in Stefania Dumbrava's PhD to bound the maximum arity of a signature and works well if you know the trick:

```
f : {ffun n -> (bound ...).-tuple A}
```

Usually `bound := \max_S ...`, so it works well with the rest of the theory.

Comment: I think you rather mean "Stefania Dumbrava's PhD".